# How to add a character in the URL using chrome?

Tags: redirect

I want to add a specific character to the URL after a specific word.

For example, if the word “games” is in the URL, I want to add a + sign right after it.

www.website.com/**games**/article5/page_1

Becomes

www.website.com/**games+**/article5/page_1

I’ve seen URL redirectors in chrome but I honestly have no idea how to implement such a thing

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry but I have no idea what you mean

Comment: You've added `google-chrome-extension` tag which is only for development of extensions, not about finding one, so I've assumed you want to develop an extension and posted a link to the official demo.

Comment: Nope I want an extension that does what I asked, or if someone can help with an extension that does this

Comment: Just to double-check - only in Chrome?

Comment: Yeah, I got a redirect extension but I don’t know how to do expressions and functions

Comment: Quoting the rules: "questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." There are other sites like superuser.com or softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.